# Difference between multiple gunicorn workers with one server instance and 1 gunicorn worker with multiple server instances

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, gunicorn

I have a django application running with gunicorn (with the gevent worker type) that is hosted on aws.

What would the difference be between having 1 gunicorn worker but with multiple instances of the app hosted and having multiple workers but only with one instance of the app hosted?

Or am I completely misunderstanding and these 2 things serve different purposes and is not related at all?

Comment: With multiple instances you would need a load balancer in front of your instances. If you have multiple workers on one instance, that means they can serve concurrent request for the same instance. If you have multiple instance with only one worker, then concurrent request would be spread across multiple instances.

Comment: @AnthonyB. Appreciate the response. Yes, the way i currently have it set up is multiple instances with a load balancer in front. Would you say that one of the ways I mentioned above is preferred over the other? Is there a benefit in having the requests concurrently served from one instance?

Comment: It depends. if you want to have a highly available application you would want to have multiple instances serving request (assuming they are in different AZ etc...) BUT, at the same time, if the CPU/memory usage of those instance is very low, then you are wasting money in those resources since they could handle more traffic, hence having more worker per instances would be better. You could reduce the number of instances to deal with a steady load and add autoscaling when more traffic is happening.